# Ruby on Rails simple_form_for all.each do

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

I am using Rails 3.0, Ruby 1.9.2 and the Plataformatec simple_form gem. This code works with a form_for but not simple_form_for:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@provider) do |f| %>
  <% Car.all.each do |c| %>
    <div>
      <%= check_box_tag :car_ids, c.id, @store.cars.include?(c), :name => 'store[car_ids][]' %>
      $<%= c.cost %> | <%= c.description %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "New" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How do I get it to work with simple_form_for?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean `don't work`? Show what happens. Show errors. Show something we can discuss

Comment: And why your model name is pluralized? I mean `Cars`

Comment: Sorry, the model wasn't supposed to be pluralized, bad copying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the controller code.

In the "new" controller action I can't simply perform:

```
@provider = Provider.new(params[:provider])
```

as one would normally.

Instead I have to process each parameter separately:

@provider.location = params[:provider][:location]
    etc...

For the Car check boxes, I add each car_id from the car_ids parameter to the "has_many" cars model association one at a time:

```
car_ids = params[:provider][:car_ids]
car_ids.each do |cid|
  @provider.cars << Car.find(cid)
end
```

Then I can call:

```
@provider.save!
```

And it saves correctly (my initial problem was that it wasn't saving the selected Cars).

For some reason, I was able to figure this out only after posting the question here. Funny how that works.

Thanks all for your replies!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `simple_form` right the same way as `form_for`.

For example ther is no any `check_box_tag` method in `simple_form` gem. There is ONLY `inuput` fields that you can specify with `:as` option. So your `check_box_tag` will be converted to

```
f.input car_ids, ..., :as => :check_box
```

Checkout Usage, Rdoc and other useful stuff https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form